# Not sure what is wrong with my Altair code for visualisation in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, altair

I'm working through a tutorial on Altair in Python.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umTwkgQoo_E

Loaded data fine.

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/onlyphantom/miband/main/data/run_1km.csv", parse_dates=['startTime'])
df['day_of_week'] = df['startTime'].dt.day_name()
df.head()
```

Got my first plots such as
alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
x = "seconds_per_km",
y = "day_of_week",
color ="day_of_week"
).interactive()
[image]

But when I try to use

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    alt.x("seconds_per_km"),
    alt.y("day_of_week"),
    alt.color("day_of_week")
).interactive()

I get an error:

Cell In[37], line 2
      1 alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
----> 2     alt.x("seconds_per_km"),
      3     alt.y("day_of_week"),
      4     alt.color("day_of_week")
      5 ).interactive()

AttributeError: module 'altair' has no attribute 'x'
```

Why? I'm running version 4.2.2

Comment: All the doc examples use named-args: `.encode(x = ..., y = ...)`

Comment: Thank you for that. i think the tutorial hints at alt.x being able to be loaded up a bit more.

Comment: It’s uppercase, `alt.X()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use upper case `alt.X` and it will work